# Pandas merging rows with the same value and same index

Tags: pandas, indexing, merge, rows

I have a DataFrame with an index called `SubjectID` and a column `Visit`. Subjects have multiple Visits and either an integer value or an N/A for `Value1` and `Value2`. I want to collapse the rows that have the same `SubjectID` and the same `Visit` number.

Here is my data frame:

```
SubjectID    Visit    Value1    Value2    
B1           1         1.57      N/A
B1           1         N/A       1.75
B1           2         N/A       1.56
```

I want to it to look like this:

```
Subject ID    Visit     Value1    Value2
B1            1          1.57      1.75
B1            2          N/A       1.56
```

I was trying to use `groupby()` to solve this problem but I'm not sure how to make it take into account both the index and the values in the `Visit` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or [`groupby.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) to get the first/last non-null value for each column within the group.  For the example data, the output would be the same for either method:

```
df = df.groupby(['SubjectID', 'Visit']).first().reset_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
  SubjectID  Visit  Value1  Value2
0        B1      1    1.57    1.75
1        B1      2     NaN    1.56
```