# Merge rows with same index and prioritize column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-munging

I have a dataframe with some duplicate index values with columns containing values for two different experiments. I want to prioritize Col_A if values are present across both index instances. I am working to solve this solution using the following algorithm.

1. Merge rows with the same index

[Pandas merging rows with the same value and same index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646345/pandas-merging-rows-with-the-same-value-and-same-index)

2. Create new column with combine_first function. to select Col_A if present otherwise select Col_B

Example Data

```
data = {'id':['id3', 'id3', 'id6'],
       'Col_A':[11,NaN,3],
       'Col_B':[NaN,5,NaN]}

## Insert SO Magic Here

##

output = {'id':['id3', 'id6'],
       'Col_Score':[11,3]}
```

If there is a "better" solution (shorter) than my proposed algorithm, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re guaranteed to not have duplicate columns per id, then the `data` (or rather `pd.DataFrame(data)`) can easily be reformatted as such:

```
>>> ser = data.set_index('id').stack()
>>> ser
id        
id3  Col_A    11.0
     Col_B     5.0
id6  Col_A     3.0
dtype: float64
```

As a side note, if you unstack it again, you get a more dense version o your original data with a unique index:

```
>>> ser.unstack()
     Col_A  Col_B
id               
id3   11.0    5.0
id6    3.0    NaN
```

We can select the first item with a groupby rather than `.unstack()`, for example:

```
>>> ser.groupby('id').first().rename('Col_score')
id
id3    11.0
id6     3.0
Name: Col_Score, dtype: float64
```

You can then `.reset_index()` onto that to get a dataframe instead of a series.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `melt`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['id'], value_name='Col_Score') # Col_A will be above Col_B
   .dropna()                                     # remove NaN rows
   .groupby('variable', as_index=False)
   .first()                                      # keep first per group (i.e. Col_A when both)
   .drop('variable', axis=1)                     # cleanup
)
```

output:

```
    id  Col_Score
0  id3       11.0
1  id3        5.0
```